# What other material could replace copper in an electric motor?

Tags: motor

In the discussion about a "what if?" question in the Worldbuilding StackExchange, I claimed that it would be near impossible to build an electric motor without copper. Other people think that any conductive metal would do, including iron, although with a lower overall efficiency.

I seem to remember that the point of having an iron core in the electromagnets was to have an high density of the magnetic field, and therefore having iron coils would disrupt the field and make the motor non functional.

Am I right ?

Comment: There is no relation between electromagnet core, which should be ferromagnetic, and the coil windings, which should be just conductive. So any conductor would do. Gold will be even better than copper, for example.

Comment: Silver is better than gold.

Comment: [Aluminium was studied](http://www.achrnews.com/articles/83673-copper-vs-aluminum-windings-in-motors) as a material for motor windings.

Comment: EE.SE is not a place for requests "I don't know fundamentals.  I haven't done research.  So prove my guesswork."

Comment: Superconducting windings have been used in experimental motors also.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Rather than damning him for his glaring error, wouldn't it make more sense to correct it gently and send him on his way with a tool he didn't have before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You CAN use any conductive metal instead of copper.  The question is what would happen if you did.  If the resistivity of the metal you use is less than copper (like silver) then you could 1) use smaller wire and therefore have a smaller motor to get the same performance as copper or 2) use the same size wire and get a more efficient motor.

Similarly, if you used a metal with higher resistivity than copper (like aluminum), then you would need bigger wire to maintain the same performance.  This would lead to either bigger motors for the same performance or less efficient motors.

Aluminum has been used in for motors but it is quite rare.